# Cast inside LINQ clause ANY

Tags: c#, linq

```
myClass
{
.....
.....
public XyzEnum Profession { get; set; }
....
}
```

I'm trying to use LINQ on list of objects like this.

```
if(myClassList.Any(x => x.Profession = XyzEnum.SpecificProfession))
{
.....
}
```

I want to compare int values of enum. How to Cast ***x.Profession*** in above code to ***int***? Below code doesn't work.

```
if(myClassList.Any(x => (int)x.Profession = (int)XyzEnum.SpecificProfession))
    {
    .....
    }
```

My aim is to check if specific Profession exist inside list or not.

Comment: Did you confuse assignment `=` and comparision `==`?

Comment: _"Below code doesn't work."_  - how EXACTLY it does not work? Does not compile? Throws at runtime? Produces wrong results?

Comment: why do you even want to do that? Are the enums of different types and happen to have the same int-values? Generally `x => x.Profession == XyzEnum.SpecificProfession` (notice you need dobule-equal-sign) should do what you want.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Does that compare the enum values regardless of enum names? I have enum names in XyzEnum different than what is there in list, but values are same. So i want to compare values.

Comment: No, you can't compare different types like `MyEnum.One == AnotherEnum.One`. So you need to casto to `int` probably, right. Alternativly cast to one of your enum-types: `MyEnum.One == (MyEnum) AnotherEnum.One`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you mixed up *assignment* (which is `=`)  with *comparison* (which is `==`). Casting anything to `int` will therefor have no effect.

So what you presumably need is this:

```
if(myClassList.Any(x => x.Profession == XyzEnum.SpecificProfession) ...
```

If your enum can have multiple values, you're better of using the [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-7.0)-method, in order to check if your enum-value *contains* a specific value:

```
if(myClassList.Any(x => x.Profession.HasFlag(XyzEnum.SpecificProfession)) ...
```

However that assumes your enum-values are marked as `Flags`:

```
[Flags]enum MyEnum
{
    One = 0,
    Two = 1,
    Three = 2,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 8 // and so on
}
```

Comment: You're correct. I mixed up assignment and comparison. First solution is working for me. Thanks.